# Create new HTML table per ROW from MySql/PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Can anyone help with how I can put each row from the below into seperate html tables.

So one table per row line, instead of just one table for the whole DB?

Would it be best to call via the int ID and populate that way?

I have a database "**dorav3**" with table name "**dtab1**" with the below columns

```
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Pillar        | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PD Team       | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PD Team ID    | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PD Team URL   | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Summary       | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PD Service    | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PD Service ID | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Outlook DL    | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Outlook Email | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Description   | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Tags          | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PD EP ID      | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PD EP URL     | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id            | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I can connect to and populate html from this with the below.

***PHP***

```
<?php

// php populate html table from mysql database
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$databaseName = "dorav3";



// connect to mysql
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);



// mysql select query
$query = "SELECT * FROM `dtab1";



$result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query);




$dataRow = "";

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $dataRow = $dataRow."<tr><td>$row2[0]</td><td>$row2[1]</td><td>$row2[2]</td><td>$row2[3]</td><td>$row2[4]</td><td>$row2[5]</td><td>$row2[6]</td><td>$row2[7]</td><td>$row2[8]</td><td>$row2[9]</td><td>$row2[10]</td><td>$row2[11]</td><td>$row2[12]</td></tr>";
}

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<title>PHP DATA ROW TABLE FROM DATABASE</title>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<style>

    table,th,tr,td
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

</style>
```

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <th>Pillar</th>
        <th>PD Team</th>
        <th>PD Team ID</th>
        <th>PD Team URL</th>
        <th>Summary</th>
        <th>PD Service</th>
        <th>PD Service ID</th>
        <th>Outlook DL</th>
        <th>Outlook Email</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Tags</th>
        <th>PD EP ID</th>
        <th>PD EP URL</th>
    </tr>

    <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row1[0];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row1[1];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row1[2];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row1[3];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row1[4];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row1[5];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row1[6];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row1[7];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row1[8];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row1[9];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row1[10];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row1[11];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row1[12];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile;?>

</table>
```

Comment: get rid of all the static table tags etc from your HTML. Then in the PHP where you do `$dataRow = $dataRow."<tr>`...etc, just add `<table>` and `</table>` to the start and end of the string.

Comment: `while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;` < that stops the loop.

Answer (score -3):

You should put the while before the table tag and the endwhile tag after the closing table tag.